# WordPress' Tribe Events leads to main page

Tags: wordpress

My client is using Tribe Events for, well, managing his events :) I was asked to make a new theme for him. I downloaded his old installation and created new theme, checked and everything was great. I uploaded the whole thing to my server - works as well. But when I finally got the thing on my client's host, every link leading to Tribe Events' content is leading back to main page. Strange thing - it happens only when my theme is on. But then again, I tried removing `tribe-events` directory from the theme, renaming it etc. Nothing helps. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide details about the way you use it so I am not sure the way to provide exact reply.
If you use it without default page template (plugin one) then you should check your loop.
Did you override any files or did you change plugin files at all.
Make sure there is no extra loop running and if you use lops on page make sure you finish it properly

And finally - try to **reset permalings**, both theme and plugin, if any

Comment: I didn't because there isn't actually anything specific to tell. Theme is pretty much normal. I found out, that the problem was using custom `WP_Query` in the `index.php` file. I renamed `index.php` to `front-page.php` and in index, I just put `get_header` and `footer` and a loop inside. It helped.